# Future Builder has Data in api but, returns Null

Tags: flutter, dart, future

I am getting a null when calling my Future builder.

I have my api setup like this:

```
Future getDriverInfo() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  var _token = prefs.getString('token');

  var dProfile;
  var url =
      'http://buddies-8269.herokuapp.com/api/driver/current_user/?access=$_token';

  await http.post(url, headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}).then(
      (http.Response response) {
    switch (response.statusCode) {
      case (200):
        var responseData = json.decode(response.body);

        DriverProfile driverProfile = DriverProfile.fromJson(responseData);
        print('Driver Info API: Got Data ${driverProfile.status.user.email}');
        dProfile = driverProfile.status;

        break;
      case (500):
        print('500 Error ${response.body}');

        break;
    }
    return dProfile;
  });
}
```

For the future builder I wrote:

```
_getInfo = getDriverInfo();

  Widget _buildDataWidget() {
    return Container(
        height: 10,
        child: FutureBuilder(
            future: getDriverInfo(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {  
              if (!snapshot.hasData == null) {
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              } else {
                var x = snapshot.data;
                print('The Drivers data is $x');
                return Container(
                  child:Text(x)
                );
              }
            }));
  }
```

The console returns "The Drivers data is null" but, when I print out the data directly from the api function, I get data. Could you let me know what I've done wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `await` keyword together with `.then` might be causing some unexpected outcomes. Rewrite the function to just use `await`.

```
  http.Response response = await http.post(url, headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"})
  switch (response.statusCode) {
    case (200):
      var responseData = json.decode(response.body);

      DriverProfile driverProfile = DriverProfile.fromJson(responseData);
      print('Driver Info API: Got Data ${driverProfile.status.user.email}');
      dProfile = driverProfile.status;

      break;
    case (500):
      print('500 Error ${response.body}');

      break;
  }
  return dProfile;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting status code other than 200 or 500 from post request. You've not handled default case in switch statement in your code snippet. Try adding a default case and check if there's some other error.

Comment: I get data after the print statement  Driver Info API: Got Data ${driverProfile.status.user.email} everything is there. Just not in the future builder